# How to make the code execute when the limit is actually reached

Tags: javascript

I have this set of code that adds a `display:none` css class to a certain element on my page. Though this works, I need the code to apply the style to the element upon the 15<sup>th</sup> input value being shown. Right now it applies the style after the input has been created and the button is clicked again. I need it to disappear on the creation of that 15<sup>th</sup> input field.

Any ideas?

```
 <script> 
>            var counter = 1; 
>            var limit = 15; 
>            function addInput(divName){
> >             if (counter == 15)  {       
>                 var el = document.getElementById('destroy');      
>                 el.style.display = "none";
> >               }
> >             else {
> >               var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
> >               newdiv.innerHTML = "<span id=''>Serial Number " + (counter + 1) + " : <input type='text' name='myInputs[]'/></span>";
> >               document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);
> >               counter++;
> >             }
> > 
> > }  </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you are trying to do this:

```
var counter = 1; 
var limit = 15; 
function addInput(divName){
  if (counter < limit)  {       
    var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
    newdiv.innerHTML = "<span id=''>Serial Number " + (counter + 1) + " : <input type='text' name='myInputs[]'/></span>";
    document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);
    counter++;
    if(counter === limit){
      var el = document.getElementById('destroy');      
      el.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That was exactly it. I am such a noob at Javascript. I'm slowly learning though and thanks to you, I now see how this works! :)

Comment: I had no idea that you could nest if statements like that. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

A simple rearrangement should do the trick:

```
function addInput(divName){
    var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
    newdiv.innerHTML = "<span id=''>Serial Number " + (counter + 1) + " : <input type='text' name='myInputs[]'/></span>";
    document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);
    counter++;
    if (counter == 15)  {       
        var el = document.getElementById('destroy');      
        el.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```